# Can you visit Hatta as a day trip from Dubai by public transport?

Tags: public-transport, dubai, uae, day-trips

Reading the [wikivoyage page on one of the areas of Dubai](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Dubai/Emirates_Road), I came across Hatta, an exclave of the Emirate of Dubai. Based on the mention on that page, and the photo on the [stub Wikivoyage page for Hatta](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Hatta), it looks an interesting (and less hot!) place to visit

Unfortunately, the [Hatta Wikivoyage page](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Hatta) is (currently) a little vague on public transport options, as seem to be the Dubai pages. I'm not sure if my budget stretches to hiring a Dubai taxi for the whole day, and I don't have a car.

Is it practical to visit Hatta on a day trip from Dubai, by public transport? And if so, where would one go in Dubai to set off from? (Bonus marks for a timetable and prices if possible!)

Comment: I didn't in the end, but one of our party did. On the way out, they were the only one on the bus for the last 30 minutes! Apparently the scenery was amazing, but there wasn't that much they could do in Hatta without a car

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can, but you should expect to spend many hours on the bus/train. The fare is **13-15 AED (2.7-3.1 GBP)** each way. The train seems to be slightly faster, but it may also involve more connections.

I'll give an example trip. This trip is estimated to take roughly 3 hours and 20 minutes each way.

---

#### To Hatta

From The **Dubai Mall 01**, take **Bus 28** in the direction of **Lamcy Plaza**. Get off at **Oud Metha Metro**.

From there, catch **Bus E16** in the direction of **Hatta**. Get off at **Hatta**.

#### Return

From Hatta **Bus Station 01**, take **Bus E16** in the direction of **Sabkha**. Get off at **Etisalat Head Office**.

From **Etisalat Head Office 1**, take **Bus 27** in the direction of the **Dubai Mall**. Get off at the **Dubai Mall**.

---

#### Travel planner

Don't use those particular instructions, though. It was just an example. Use this [travel planner](http://wojhati.rta.ae/dub/XSLT_TRIP_REQUEST2?language=en) to get up-to-date times and the perfect route for you.